# How to get all the days of a selected week?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, calendar

I have a situation, where i have to get all the days of the selected week. Ex. I have selected  July/23/2015,then I have to get July/19/2015 to July/25/2015.Any solution would be grateful.

Comment: show what you have tried so far

Comment: Not really a javascript question, but it's clear enough that someone might help.

Comment: http://www.tikalk.com/incubator/week-picker-using-jquery-ui-datepicker/   I tried this i got. but i want in normal calendar.  I used week picker. Any solution would grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use very powerful library here: http://momentjs.com/

With MomentJS, your solution will be:

```
var selectedDate = moment("July/23/2015");
var startOfWeek = selectedDate.startOf("week");
var endOfWeek = selectedDate.endOf("week");

startOfWeek.toDate(); // => Sun Jul 19 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (ICT)
endOfWeek.toDate(); // => Sat Jul 25 2015 23:59:59 GMT+0700 (ICT)
```

Comment: I got endOfWeek.toDate();, but not getting startOfWeek.toDate(); . Any help

Comment: Thanks  @Long Nguyen. for your support. I did it.